# Adding events to detect when all dynamically added scripts are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, addeventlistener, jquery-events

There are no errors thrown in the code, so I can only assume either the events aren't getting triggered or they aren't getting added properly. Can anyone determine what the issue is here?

Code below. [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/UGa6S/).

```
$('#fake-body').append('init<br />');
var scriptTag,
scriptsLoaded = 0,
scripts = ['//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js', '//codeorigin.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js'],
scriptLoadedCallback = function(val) {
  scriptsLoaded++;
  $('#fake-body').append('callback called for '+val+' | scriptsloaded = '+scriptsloaded+' & length = '+scripts.length+'<br />');
  if(scriptsLoaded === scripts.length) {
    $('#fake-body').append('all loaded');
  }
};

$.each(scripts, function(index, value) {
  $('#fake-body').append('preparing '+value+'<br />');
  scriptTag = document.createElement('script');
  scriptTag.type = 'text/javascript';
  scriptTag.src = value;
  if(typeof scriptTag.addEventListener !== 'undefined') {
    $('#fake-body').append('add event for good browsers<br />');
    scriptTag.addEventListener('load', (function() {
      scriptLoadedCallback(value);
    }), false);
  } else {
    $('#fake-body').append('add event for the other one<br />');
    scriptTag.attachEvent('onreadystatechange', function() {
      if(scriptTag.readyState === 'loaded') {
        scriptLoadedCallback(value);
      }
    });
  }
  $('#fake-body').append('appending script<br />');
  $('#fake-body').append(scriptTag);
});

$('#fake-body').append('complete');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use plain Javascript to load javascript files rather than jquery(because jquery won't fire the load callback in your current code), so replace :

```
$('#fake-body').append(scriptTag);
```

with:

```
$('#fake-body')[0].appendChild(scriptTag);
```

or if you insist to use jquery, you have to respect the following statements order (or use [getScript](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/)):

```
$body.append(scriptTag);
scriptTag.attachEvent
scriptTag.src = scriptUrl;
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UGa6S/1/)

you have another error by referencing `scriptsloaded`  rather than `scriptsLoaded` in the callback.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see this!? But I guess this is what I get for writing code at 3am... :P Thanks!